# Do I have to worry about default actions using ENUM?

Tags: java, enums

I'd like to ask you if I have to fill 'default' in the switch and 'else' in if statement while I'm using ENUM?

In other words is it ok to write a part of code like this:

```
enum Color {
    RED, BLUE   
}
```

```
void whatColor(Color c) {
    if(c == Color.RED) { 
        System.out.println("It's red");
    } else {
        System.out.println("It's blue");
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends: How confident are you that `GREEN` will never be added as a possible enum value at any point in the future?

Comment: I object to this question being closed. If the question had been "what editor is the best", by all means vote to close because it is purely opinion based with an infinite set of preference answers. This question on the other hand is a simple yes/no answer which can be answered ("No, it is not a good way to write code") based on *specific expertise*, e.g. software maintenance perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you consider OK

If you consider OK that the code works as expected as of now, and the Enum is never ever going to change then yes, it may be said that is OK

Probably it will not be the case so aim for flexibility and change of requirements:

- What happens when you add a new color? do you really want to say that is `BLUE`?
- What happens when the color is `null`, that may represent `unkown`?

For the first question you may cover the method with a unit test.

For the second question I would at least add a `UNKOWN` and/or `NO_COLOR` value to the color and use them for the `else` branch accordingly.

Comment: I forgot about null and indeed it can be a problem. Thanks a lot.